# What does 'opening storyline' mean in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary, nouns

Today I was studying my physics textbook and this sentence shows up

"....filling the tank of your car **in the opening storyline** with gasoline."

I can't seem to understand what it means. Google says storyline is just another word for *plot line*, which I am familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot as the story opens.

This probably means, "Like an incident in the beginning of the plot" -- if the story is about a character going on a trip, this is something that would kick it off.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

That is from a book "Physics for Scientists and Engineers", found here:
[Google Books "Physics etc."](https://tinyurl.com/ycf988hr)

It seems that "storyline" is pedagogic device used in the book. To quote from the book,

> "Each chapter in this book will begin with a paragraph related to a **storyline** that runs throughout the text."

Comment: The complete sentence is : *Matter transfer involves situations in which matter physically crosses the boundary of a system, carrying energy with it. Examples include filling the tank of your car **in the opening storyline** with gasoline.*  The book starts each chapter with a picture (relevant to the topics in that chapter) and a description of the picture, to give a rough idea of what we get to study in that chapter. This is what they call a *storyline* at the beginning of each chapter. I could not understand it, hence I posted it. Thanks a lot for clarifying it